# Django - Not Migrating

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, backend

I just made a new app called Recipes as I am new to Django and writing a test project and I came across this error when I made a model called Recipes and imported to `admin.py`

I would like suggestions and code snippets please.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/CodesAtom/TheLearning/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/CodesAtom/TheLearning/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/CodesAtom/TheLearning/Recipes/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Recipes)
  File "/home/thelordthemythxwz/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 117, in register
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

The admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from .models import Recipes

admin.site.register(Recipes)
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Recipes():
    title = models.TextField()
    ingredients  = models.TextField()
    directions  = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Show your admin.py and models.py

Comment: The class `Recipes` must inherit from `models.Model`. Example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#quick-example